# How to use custom view constructors that are appropriate to the build version?

Tags: java, android

I have just created the very basic implementation of my custom viewgroup and the constructors look something like this:

```
 public cardLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null,0,0);

}
public cardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    this(context, attrs,0,0);
}
public cardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

    this(context,attrs,defStyleAttr,0);
}

public cardLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr,defStyleRes);
}
```

This is where my problems come into play. Basically, the 4th constructor is for api version 21 and up. Therefore, my program will crash when api lower than version 21 is running due to the fact that all the other constructor points to the version 21 constructor. Is there anyway I can solve this?

Note: I did try to use `if (Build.Version.SDK_INT >= Build.Version_Code.Lollipop)` to check for whether a build version is higher than lollipop. If it is then do the constructor `super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr,defStyleRes)` and if it is not then do `super(context,attrs,defStyleAttr)`. However, android studio keep on giving me an error saying that super must be the first line that I call and everytime I run it my app would crash.

Comment: Call the equivalent super constructor instead of forwarding it to the fourth one

Comment: Thanks that seem to solve my problem but the problem now become if I need to do some initialization at the beginning do I have to do it in everyone of them?

Comment: declare a private method that do the initialization and call it in each constructor.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Problem solve.